# How to run Nested Stored Proc via python pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a python script that is running a stored proc on an SQL Server, that Main Stored Proc would spawn Child Stored Proc in loop. However, the procedure exits after only 1 loop. I have cursor.commit() in my python code. I want to run commit each time one iteration of Child SP is done. How do I implement this.

Python Code:

```
    cursor.execute("{CALL main_prc_name(arg1,?,?)}", arg2,arg3)
    cursor.commit()
```

Wrapper SP:

```
    BEGIN
        while @months >= 0 
        begin
            -- some code for validation
            begin
                exec dbo.child_proc @arg1, @arg2;
            end
            set @months=@months-1;
        end
    END
```

Comment: You might need to provide more code for someone to answer your question. As it is, if @months = 0 in the wrapper SP then the WHILE loop will only run once. Also, the wrapper SP does not return until the end of the while loop so you can not call `cursor.commit()` in your Python for each run of the child SP.

Comment: Figured as  such, I had to go ahead and implement the wrapper logic in python, and I am now calling the child function directly from python instead of using a nested Stored Proc. It runs fine when I run a single stored proc from python.